# Python returning instance of class from list

Tags: python

I try to get index of instance of object in a list. And I don't know how to do it without for-loop.

If someone can show me right direction, without for-looping it.

I find that list has instance of it with any()-function but can't get index out of it.

I try to clarify my problem. If any()-fucntion can find that list(self.data) has instance of object. any()-function returns only true/false. Is there function or way to get index of that instance so i can call it.

And code:

```
class MyClass: 

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.data = []
        self.f = open(f, "rb")
        self.mod = sys.modules[__name__]

    def readFile(self):
        f = self.f
        try:
            self.head = f.read(8)
            while True:
                length = f.read(4)
                if length == b'':
                    break
                c = getattr(self.mod, f.read(4).decode())
                if any(isinstance(x, c) for x in self.data):
                    index = self.data.index(c) #Problem is here
                    self.data[index].append(f.read(int(length.hex(), 16)))
                else:
                    obj = c(data=f.read(int(length.hex(), 16)))
                    self.data.append(obj)
                f.read(4) #TODO check CRC
        finally:
            f.close()
```

Comment: Maybe you should set `self.data = []` in init instead of at the class level?

Comment: Can you provide an example file that you are reading from?

Comment: Good point, @JohnZwinck. Code is for learning purposes and if there is any purposes or comments what I have done wrong, I'm happy to hear about them.

Comment: @Evus: OK, try changing that.

Comment: `isinstance(c)` requires two arguments, not one.

Comment: What is that "problem" line supposed to do? Why are you calling `isinstance(c)` there?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `index()` take as argument an object instance? You are passing `isinstance(c)` where `c` is a module attribute?

Comment: Editted. Tried to clarify my problem. Out-of-topic is it easier if i just use OrderedDict and not list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate` is the way to go here.

```py
...
c = getattr(self.mod, f.read(4).decode())
found = [ (i, x) for (i,x) in enumerate(self.data) if isinstance(x, c) ]
if len(found) > 0:
    index, val = found[0]
    ...
```

Comment: Nice one, but I think you need the `if isinstance(x, c)` to only store instances of `c` in `found` (also missing `]`)

Comment: @urban: Oups! I just forgot the end of the expression :-( . Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you. Just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on getting the instance of the object and its index in the `self.data` list:

```
# ...

# This gives you back a class name I assume?
c = getattr(self.mod, f.read(4).decode())

# The following would give you True/False ... which we don't need
# any(isinstance(x, c) for x in self.data)

# Now, this will return _all_ the instances of `c` in data
instances = [x for x in self.data if isinstance(x, c)]


if len(instances):
    # Assuming that only 1 instance is there
    index = self.data.index(instances[0])
    # ??? What do you append here?
    self.data[index].append()
else:
    obj = c(data=f.read(int(length.hex(), 16)))
    self.data.append(obj)

f.read(4) #TODO check CRC
```